# swig 3.0.1 , python 3 and bool data types

Tags: python, c++, swig

I'm updating my bindings to support swig 3.0.1 , but I'm getting an error when trying to call a function that expects a boolean (it was not happening before with 2.0.9)...
Specifically:

TypeError: in method 'MClass_setStatus', argument 2 of type 'bool'

Any hint on what actually changed ?

Comment: a little more information, seems that the bindings now wants an explicit cast to bool when calling it from python, like setStatus(bool(1)). Anyone can suggest a typemap to revert it back like in Swig 2 where an int is casted to bool automatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need backward compatibility so this isn't an acceptable option. I was able to override the behaviour to the legacy one using -DSWIG_PYTHON_LEGACY_BOOL on the swig command line

Answer (score 0):

You can export your function with a different but compatible signature. In your case declare the export of your func to take int instead of bool. SWIG will generate the wrapper code for int, but the compiler will call your bool function at the c++ level (unless you have a book overload). There are no overloads in python so I don't know if the SWIG wrapper code will flag an error if you give a bool as call parameter. Swig may not like implicit int -> bool but it might be OK with implicit bool -> int.